# Visual Studio 2013 Crashed after Update 2?

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2013, updates

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 (my OS is Windows 8).
After installing, whenever I open Visual Studio I got the following error :

[image: VS 2013 Error]

It's OK until here, but if I open a project, Visual Studio crash

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Crashed after Update 2]

Last records in ActivityLog.xml :

```
<entry>
    <record>964</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:45.997</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{A6EFEF5F-BE9B-432A-ADFE-74A119AB4478}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>965</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:45.997</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [JSONPackage]</description>
    <guid>{A6EFEF5F-BE9B-432A-ADFE-74A119AB4478}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>966</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:45.998</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [JSONPackage]</description>
    <guid>{A6EFEF5F-BE9B-432A-ADFE-74A119AB4478}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSON.Package.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>967</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:46.013</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [JSONPackage]</description>
    <guid>{A6EFEF5F-BE9B-432A-ADFE-74A119AB4478}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSON.Package.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>968</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:54.439</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{60116BB0-6F13-49E2-A1CE-A185C783B68B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>969</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:54.439</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ScssPackage]</description>
    <guid>{60116BB0-6F13-49E2-A1CE-A185C783B68B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>970</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:54.498</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [ScssPackage]</description>
    <guid>{60116BB0-6F13-49E2-A1CE-A185C783B68B}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load type 'Microsoft.Scss.Editor.ScssPackage' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>971</record>
    <time>2014/05/20 19:38:54.498</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ScssPackage]</description>
    <guid>{60116BB0-6F13-49E2-A1CE-A185C783B68B}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load type 'Microsoft.Scss.Editor.ScssPackage' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I also checked windows error logs :

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Crashed after Update 2]

1:

```
Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2014-06-19T18:46:39Z. Error Code: 0x80070005.
```

2:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.30501.0, time stamp: 0x5361f453
Faulting module name: csproj.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524fcb78
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0003151e
Faulting process ID: 0x15d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf74627d760129
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\VCSPackages\csproj.dll
Report ID: 7b06404e-e056-11e3-8172-74f06dc3132d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

3:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskBody.DoWork(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTask, UInt32, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTask[], System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask+<>c__DisplayClass29.<GetCallbackForMultipleParent>b__28(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Object>[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask+<>c__DisplayClass2f.<GetCallback>b__2e()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TaskSchedulerService.VsUIThreadBlockableTaskScheduler.DoOneTask()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TaskSchedulerService.VsIdleTimeScheduler.FDoIdle(UInt32)
```

4:

```
Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2014-06-19T18:46:39Z. Error Code: 0x80070005.
```

5:

```
Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2014-06-19T18:46:39Z. Error Code: 0x80070005.
```

How can I fix the problem ?

**Edit:**
The problem doesn't solve with re installing update 2.

Comment: Silly question I know, but have you tried disabling all extensions?  It may be that one of the extensions is not functioning correctly with Update 2.

Comment: I run devenv.exe in safe mode with `devenv /safemode`, but I got the error again. Safe mode must disable all extensions, I think so.

Comment: As far as I know yes - that disables all extensions. Do you always get the error regarding JSON?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I don't think so the problem was related to extensions

Comment: Try and manually uninstall all JSON packages. Then at least you can identify if that is the cause or not.  It could be that a re-install of JSON could solve the issue (maybe it will 'register' properly after Update 2 'broke' the registration).

Comment: I couldn't resolve the problem until reinstalling windows os

Comment: That's harsh.  Normally a VS re-install fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the extension: "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript."  This was updated as part of  VS 2013 Update 2.

If you uninstall this extension, the error messages should go away.  This must be done from the "Programs and Features" control panel window outside of Visual Studio.

After uninstalling this and restarting Visual Studio, it will say that it is still installed (for me, anyways).  However, the errors should go away.

Comment: This hit me yesterday with Update 4.  I was able to fix it selecting a repair on "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript" rather than a complete Uninstall using your method above.

Answer (score 0):

Running VSE 2013 for Web, did Update 4, got above message:
CreateInstance failed for package [JSONPackage]
Checked Control Panel, I had VSE for JS v1.0.9200.20789 AS WELL AS and 2.1.30324.53 installed. First I uninstalled the older version, tried loading VSE, got same message.
Then uninstalled other instance of newer version, got same message.
Then tried "Repair" of Update 4, will see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case VS2013 Update 5, I had exactly the same issue. I solved it uninstalling all the Resharper Extensions.

Resharper -> Extension Manager -> Installed extensions