# Project does not load after installing visual studio 2013 update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After installing Visual Studio Professional 2013 update 2, I get the following error :

"No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name: 
 Adornments/HighlichtCurrentLine/Enable
 Parameters name: optionId"

ActivityLog contains the following error:

```
<entry>
    <record>883</record>
    <time>2014/06/13 10:10:10.411</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Construction of frame content failed.&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{0f887920-c2b6-11d2-9375-0080c747d9a0}&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame caption: Find Results 1&#x000D;&#x000A;Exception details:&#x000D;&#x000A;System.ArgumentException: No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name: Adornments/HighlightCurrentLine/Enable&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: optionId&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.EditorOptions.Implementation.EditorOptionsFactoryService.GetOptionDefinitionOrThrow(String optionId)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.EditorOptions.Implementation.EditorOptions.SetOptionValue(String optionId, Object value)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.EditorOptions.Implementation.EditorOptions.SetOptionValue[T](EditorOptionKey`1 key, T value)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.SetPropertiesToToolWindowDefaults()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.Init_SetSite(Object pUnkSite)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.SetSite(Object pUnkSite)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()</description>
</entry>
```

A search on the internet for this problem did not yield a solution.

This question seems unrelated:
[Visual Studio 2013 Crashed after Update 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774007/visual-studio-2013-crashed-after-update-2)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to repair it in Control Panel -> Programs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rerunning the installation and selecting repair fixed the issue.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error)

```
1.Close Visual Studio
2.Open the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\
3.Rename the ComponentModelCache folder
4.Restart Visual Studio.
```

Answer (score 11):

I had also faced the same issue after I installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.
I’ve Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition.

As suggested on this link:
http://gerardbeckerleg.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-for-the-given-option-name/#comment-259

I installed Web Essentials 2013 for VS 2013 and the issue of not opening code files resolved.

Here is link for Web Essentials 2013:-
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361

Comment: Confirmed this also works on Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Answer (score 5):

"No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name: Adornments/HighlichtCurrentLine/Enable Parameters name: optionId"

Conrol Panel -> Programs -> Find Visual Studio -> right click -> repair

Comment: I tried this but right clicking on Visual Studio didn't give a repair option, it gave only "Change". The program listed is Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 4.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not the cause of your crash, but I got a similar error twice and I have fixed it like so:

I had VisualSVN installed in VS2013. Once I've unistalled it (from Windows' "Uninstall or Change a Program") everything was OK.
Then I've re-installed it.

Seems like it was caused by newly installed addons messing up VisualSVN's setup...
(In my case VS2013 crashed during launch.)

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I had same problem. I updated windows 7 updates this morning and could not restart VS 2013 after that. When saw extension AnkhSVN was disabled and could not remove or update it. Uninstalling from control fixed the problem. thanks